# Calling PL/SQL procedure with user defined record as its IN parameter using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc, record

I am trying to call the following PL/SQL procedure that takes a user defined record type as an `IN` parameter.

```sql
   -- User Defined Record
   TYPE EMP_REC IS RECORD
   (
    id employees.employee_id%type,
    name employees.last_name%type,
    dept_name departments.department_name%type,
    job_title jobs.job_title%type,
    salary employees.salary%type,
    manager_id employees.employee_id%type,
    city locations.city%type,
    phone employees.phone_number%type
   );
```

Here is the definition of the user defined record:

```sql
  -- PURPOSE: Prints all employee information from the employee record 
  -- Example Of: PROCEDURE that takes in a parameter of RECORD type 
  PROCEDURE print_employee_all_details(empl1 emp_rec , emp_rec_string OUT VARCHAR2)
```

I was looking at the [Oracle JDBC Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraint.htm#JJDBC28180) that indicated JDBC does not support composite types like RECORDS:

[image]

Searching the internet took me to [this link](http://betteratoracle.com/posts/31-passing-record-types-between-oracle-and-java)

Here is the code that I tried to pass a user defined record to a PL/SQL procedure:

```java
public String printEmployeeAllDetails() {
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    String empDetails = null;

    try {
        // Register the Jdbc Driver
        // Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_ORACLE);

        // Create a Database Connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PWD);

        // Create a query string
        String callProc = "{call HR.EMP_PKG.print_employee_all_details( ? , ?) }";

        // Create a Callable Statement
        callStmt = conn.prepareCall(callProc);


        // Create descriptor for the Oracle Record type "EMP_REC" required
        StructDescriptor recDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("EMP_REC", conn);

        // Stage values for each field in the Oracle record in an array
        Object[] javaEmpRec = new Object[8];


        // Populate those values in the Array
        javaEmpRec[0] = 100;
        javaEmpRec[1] = "Joe Matthew";
        javaEmpRec[2] = "IT";
        javaEmpRec[3] = "Senior Consultant";
        javaEmpRec[4] = 20000;
        javaEmpRec[5] = 101;
        javaEmpRec[6] = "lombard";
        javaEmpRec[7] = "222333444";

        // Cast the java array into the oracle record type
        STRUCT oracleEmpRec = new STRUCT(recDescriptor, conn, javaEmpRec);


        // Bind Values to the IN parameter
        callStmt.setObject(1, oracleEmpRec);

        // Register OUT parameter
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

        // Execute the Callable Statement
        callStmt.execute();

        // Retrieve the value from the OUT parameter
        empDetails = callStmt.getString(2);
        System.out.println("Emp Details: " + empDetails);

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in the database");
        System.out.println("Exception message: " + se.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Database error code: " + se.getErrorCode());
        se.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Clean up
        if (callStmt != null) {
            try {
                callStmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return empDetails;
}
```

On running this code I get the following exception:

```
Exception occured in the database
Exception message: invalid name pattern: HR.EMP_REC
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: HR.EMP_REC
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:554)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:471)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.initPickler(StructDescriptor.java:324)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.<init>(StructDescriptor.java:254)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:135)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:103)
Database error code: 17074
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(StructDescriptor.java:72)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.printEmployeeAllDetails(HrManager.java:1214)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.main(HrManager.java:1334)
```

I am using the `ojdbc6.jar` the very first jar under heading `JDBC Thin for All Platforms` for  `Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4) JDBC Drivers`[on this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html).

**I want to know if passing user defined records (as IN parameter) to a PL/SQL procedure is allowed ?  Has anybody tried doing the above ?**

Comment: As I can understand, you want to find any indirect way (because direct way is not supported) to pass a record to procedure, yes?

Comment: yup that's the attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed to pass user-defined datatypes as IN parameters using JDBC.  But it can't be a `RECORD`.  It must be a schema level object, e.g.

```sql
CREATE TYPE EMP_REC AS OBJECT
(
 id employees.employee_id%type,
 name employees.last_name%type,
 dept_name departments.department_name%type,
 job_title jobs.job_title%type,
 salary employees.salary%type,
 manager_id employees.employee_id%type,
 city locations.city%type,
 phone employees.phone_number%type
);
```

In your PL/SQL, you could change references to your record to your new object type, or you could write a quick little translator function to translate the object type to the record type if you can't change the rest of the code.

Comment: We cannot create a object type with **%type**

Comment: That's not true anymore in Oracle 12c. You can now interact with package-defined records using jdbc: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC28913

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute anonymous PL/SQL block (as I know, it is possible), you can execute following:

```
declare
  rec EMP_REC;
begin
  rec.id := :ID;
  rec.name:= :NAME;
  -- and so on, rest of fields of record...
  ...
  my_procedure(rec);
end;
/
```

In this case you don't need create new database objects or change existing. You just need to pass values of parameters to fill a record.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to pass records. Because it has to be SQL object to be referred, not a pure `PL/SQL` object.

Creating an object would be like,

```sql
   -- User Defined Record
   CREATE TYPE EMP_REC AS OBJECT
   (
    id  NUMBER,
    name VARCHAR2(100),
    dept_name ...,
    job_title ..,
    salary ..,
    manager_id ..,
    city ..,
    phone ...
   );
```

And it is again a pain though. You cannot use `TYPE` attribute here. Because a TYPE cannot have a dependency that way. **Instead specify the exact datatype.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complement [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113473/521799) which suggests you could use an anonymous PL/SQL block through JDBC and compose your `RECORD` types manually and explicitly. If you're looking for a solution for that single stored procedure, then writing that block manually will do. But if you're looking for a *general solution* that generates code for *all* procedures that have `IN`, `OUT`, or `IN OUT` `RECORD` parameters, you should probably write a code generator that generates stubs based on the following query

```sql
SELECT
  x.TYPE_OWNER, x.TYPE_NAME, x.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.ARGUMENT_NAME ATTR_NAME,
  a.SEQUENCE ATTR_NO, a.TYPE_OWNER ATTR_TYPE_OWNER,
  nvl2(a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.TYPE_NAME, NULL) package_name,
  COALESCE(a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.TYPE_NAME, a.DATA_TYPE) ATTR_TYPE_NAME,
  a.DATA_LENGTH LENGTH, a.DATA_PRECISION PRECISION, a.DATA_SCALE SCALE
FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME,
    MIN(a.OWNER) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) OWNER,
    MIN(a.PACKAGE_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) PACKAGE_NAME,
    MIN(a.SUBPROGRAM_ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) SUBPROGRAM_ID,
    MIN(a.SEQUENCE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) SEQUENCE,
    MIN(next_sibling) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) next_sibling,
    MIN(a.DATA_LEVEL) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) DATA_LEVEL
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lead(a.SEQUENCE, 1, a.SEQUENCE) OVER (
        PARTITION BY a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID, a.DATA_LEVEL
        ORDER BY a.SEQUENCE ASC
      ) next_sibling,
      a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, 
      a.SUBPROGRAM_ID, a.SEQUENCE, a.DATA_LEVEL, a.DATA_TYPE
    FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS a
    WHERE a.OWNER IN ('MY_SCHEMA')     -- Possibly replace schema here
    ) a
  WHERE (a.TYPE_OWNER IN ('MY_SCHEMA') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND a.OWNER         IN ('MY_SCHEMA') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND a.DATA_TYPE      = 'PL/SQL RECORD')
  GROUP BY a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME
  ) x
ON ((a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID) = ((x.OWNER, x.PACKAGE_NAME, x.SUBPROGRAM_ID))
AND a.SEQUENCE BETWEEN x.SEQUENCE AND next_sibling
AND a.DATA_LEVEL = (x.DATA_LEVEL + 1))
ORDER BY x.TYPE_OWNER ASC, x.TYPE_NAME ASC, x.TYPE_SUBNAME ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC
```

This will provide you formal definitions of all the `RECORD` types in all the packages contained in the `MY_SCHEMA` schema, from which you can generate stubs that look like the one in Dmitry's answer:

```sql
declare
  rec EMP_REC;
begin
  rec.id := :ID;
  rec.name:= :NAME;
  -- and so on, rest of fields of record...
  ...
  my_procedure(rec);
end;
/
```

[See more details about this technique in this blog post (from which the query was taken)](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/).

Answer (score 0):

I know the original poster mentioned they use ojdbc6 but I wanted to provide a more up-to-date solution if you use a more recent ojdbc driver (I can confirm my solution works in ojdbc8).  If the record is defined in the package, then you can create a class that implements OracleData that matches the record type.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/Oracle-object-types.html#GUID-5905674A-A045-40B1-96DE-726761517D50

In the toJDBCObject method, just use createStruct

```
public class EmpRec implements OracleData {

    //getters/setters for all the fields

    @Override
    public Object toJDBCObject(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {

        return arg0.createStruct("PKG_NAME.EMP_REC", new Object[] {employeeId, lastName, departmentName, ...etc...});
    }
}
```