# How to pass a table type as parameter into an oracle stored procedure from java

Tags: java, oracle10g

I would like to call a stored procedure (call_bobo_api) in Oracle from java code. The problem I have is that the stored procedure takes a user defined table as parameter. This parameter is IN OUT. See below.

The heading of the procedure is:

```
  PROCEDURE call_bobo_api(pi_bobo_input_tab IN OUT bobo_input_tabtype,
                          po_overtime       OUT    VARCHAR2)
```

The pi_bobo_input_tab parameter is a user defined parameter. Its type is bobo_input_tabtype

```
TYPE bobo_input_rectype IS RECORD ( person_id      VARCHAR2(10),
                                  duty_date      DATE,
                                  old_book_on    NUMBER(6),
                                  book_on        NUMBER(6),
                                  old_book_off   NUMBER(6),
                                  book_off       NUMBER(6),
                                  bobo_type      VARCHAR2(1),
                                  duty_code      VARCHAR2(8),
                                  narrative      VARCHAR2(1000),
                                  working_type   VARCHAR2(10),
                                  authoriser     NUMBER,
                                  notice_date    DATE,
                                  forced_voluntry_fv  VARCHAR2(1),
                                  previous_day   VARCHAR2(1),   
                                  shift_length_only BOOLEAN,
                                  due_notice     VARCHAR2(1),
                                  by_others      VARCHAR2(1),
                                  split_ind      VARCHAR2(1),
                                  recall_ind     VARCHAR2(1),                                      
                                  bobo_main_id   NUMBER(20),
                                  bobo_detail_id NUMBER(20),
                                  trans_type     VARCHAR2(1),
                                  planned_duty   VARCHAR2(10),
                                  user_name      VARCHAR2(30), 
                                  auto_created   VARCHAR2(1),
                                  user_defined   VARCHAR2(4),
                                  extended_exc_start NUMBER(6),
                                  extended_exc_end   NUMBER(6)
```

The stored procedure call already is used in PLSQL code. I need to be able to reuse the API call (call_bobo_api) in java. My issue is that I don't know how to create a PLSQL table in java so that I can call the API.

Anyone that can put me on the right track is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

EDIT

The "Invalid name pattern: DMS_DBA.BOBO_INPUT_RECTYPE" error I am getting is caused by the code below...

```
recDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("DMS_DBA.BOBO_INPUT_RECTYPE",pconn.getConnection());
```

...and the plsql side is

```
TYPE bobo_input_tabtype IS TABLE OF bobo_input_rectype INDEX by BINARY_INTEGER;
```

The schema name is DMS_DBA and the package is called DBPK_TM_BOBO_WRAPPER_API.I wonder what the first parameter's value should be in the `StructDescriptor.createDescriptor()` method call

Thanks

Comment: [How to call oracle stored procedure which include user-defined type in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java) and [Calling PL/SQL procedure with user defined record as its IN parameter using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113075/calling-pl-sql-procedure-with-user-defined-record-as-its-in-parameter-using-jdbc)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has certainly helped and put me on the right track.  At the moment I'm getting blocked with the following error: "Invalid name pattern: DMS_DBA.BOBO_INPUT_RECTYPE"

Comment: I solved this issue by changing the bobo_input_rectype to be an OBJECT in PLSQL. This has to be done at schema level and the new object gets created into the Types folder of SQL Developer. Then in the Java code when creating the StructDescritor, the first parameter is the path of the Oracle object in capital letters. In my case "DMS_DBA.BOBO_INPUT_RECTYPE"

One more thing I had to do was to give execute grants to the oracle user on bobo_input_rectype Object.

Thanks to @rgettman for putting me on the right track